# Delete all Error messages at once from Crawl Log - Error Message page

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, search, enterprise-search

How to delete content source error messages at once from sharepoint search service application,
when i run full crawl for a content source when i search in Crawl Log - Error Message  page i found 300 errors there is any way to delete all error messages at once

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to delete the error messages? The messages are there to show you that there have been issues crawling the items referenced by the errors. Each error will need to be investigated to corrected, at which point the next time the item is crawled successfully, the error will disappear.

Comment: I am curious too. Why delete the messages?